# How to manually install Java 9 (from a tar.gz file)?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, java, tar

I've just downloaded jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz from official oracle website. Their [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-linux-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-1CDD695D-C02B-4FDB-8A50-B98ED3936B60) was not complete as I excpected. For Java 8 I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) beautifully written and explained guide with no problem. However some of the steps there, I believe can be practically different for Java 9. For example there's no such a thing as jdk-9.0.4/jre nor could you find a way to enable the Mozzila Plugin correctly? and without these steps I could not be able to run (bash) a [RapidMiner Studio](http://rapidminer.com)  which I couldn't recognize it was the software which is only executable on earlier Javas or me who didn't install Java 9 properly.
Thank you in advance.